# e-mail attachment + iOS 4.3.3

Tags: ios, ios4, email-attachments

I'm developing an app where the user can take up to 3 photo's which will eventually be added as attachment to an e-mail.

On an iPhone 3G with 4.2.1 AND on an iPhone 4 with 5.0.1 this works correctly, I can loop through the singleton and add the photo's from a dictionary to the attachment.

On an iPhone 4 with 4.3.3 the last photo will be added to the attachment but not correctly. The other two have a preview but the third one is added as a file (as seen in the screenshot below).

After receiving the mail with the attachments the third photo is only 4kb of size and when opened, only contains the icon.

The strange thing is, it works on an older device with an older iOS version, so I assume this is an OS bug.

Does anyone had any problems with iOS 4.3.3 and attachments? Am I doing something wrong? Is this a known bug with a known fix?

If you need any extra info, please dont hesitate to ask.

Regards,

Jasper

[image: screenshot]

EDIT:

This has been reported to Apple and will be handled as a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:

Apple replied:

Hi,

This is a follow-up to Bug ID# 10826049.

Engineering has provided the following feedback regarding this issue:

If this works correctly with iOS 5.0.1 we currently have no plans to release a fix specifically for iOS 4.3.3.

If you have any questions or concern regarding this issue, please update your report directly (http://bugreport.apple.com).

Thank you for taking the time to notify us of this issue.

Regards,